# How to pass value from jQuery menu to Play framework

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, playframework

I recently start working with play framework. I'm trying to use jQuery with my templates in play, and I don't know how to pass value from jQuery to play. Here is my controller:

```
public static Result createProduct() {
    String usernameSes = session("username");
    String name = newProduct.bindFromRequest().get().name;
    String desc = newProduct.bindFromRequest().get().desc;
    Double price = newProduct.bindFromRequest().get().price;
    **String category = newProduct.bindFromRequest().get.category;**
    Product.create(name, desc, price);
    return ok(showProduct.render(usernameSes, name, desc, price));
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
        <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#category" ).selectmenu(); 
            });
         </script>
        <style>
            fieldset {
            border: 0;
            }
        label {
            display: block;
            margin: 30px 0 0 0;
        }
        select {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .overflow {
            height: 200px;
        }
         </style>

        <body>

        <div class="demo">

        <form action="#">

        <fieldset>
        <label for="category">Kategorija</label>
        <select name="category" id="cathegory">
            <option selected="selected">Vozila</option>
            <option>Nekretnine</option>
            <option>Mobilni uređaji</option>
            <option>Kompjuteri</option>
            <option>Tehnika</option>
            <option>Nakit i satovi</option>
            <option>Moj dom</option>
            <option>Biznis i industrija</option>
            <option>Životinje</option>
            <option>Odjeća i obuća</option>
            <option>Ostale kategorije</option>
        </select>


        </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have an address on your routes file linked to the method on your controller ([see here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting)).

Then the `action` in your form should use that address. Using Play templates, you can even use the syntax

```
<form action="@routes.YourControllerClass.createProduct()">
```

Then, when the form will be submitted the `createProduct()` method will take care of it.

Hope it helps.